# Proteus Simulation examples for ATMEL AVR Controller

Tags: avr, simulation, proteus

I am looking for some examples for simulating AVR controller based designs in Proteus. 
Currently I do not have any board and Proteus look promising.

Is there any authentic reference?  Can some one give a link for the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Me and my friends created a [blog](http://embeddedmastrex.blogspot.in/) specially for AVR & 8051 MCU. It contains both code and proteus simulation along with a video. Have a look at it.!

Comment: Awesome man!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Hope you will add more designs soon.

Comment: Thanks. We will be uploading programs for pic, arduino and many more soon.!